# linker error - libraries in SDL - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

I used to work with SDL many times before but setting it up is a real pain in the rear. I am getting errors like that: "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit" over and over again. I added directories, added specific libraries to linker (i tried both x32 and x64) and I am still getting same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you link against both, the libsdl and libsdlmain libraries. It appears that libsdlmain is missing.

Comment: Yes, i link both. Whilst waiting for answer I switched to Dev Cpp cause you can download SDL via update service. I dont really want to waste more time on setting it up, but still im willing to know the solution (just for future). I hope I will manage to set up SDL_image as well.

Comment: Did you download "SDL2-devel-2.0.3-VC.zip" from here http://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php?